# Tabular environment column specification

Tags: tables, columns

I am using the `tabular` environment.

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
{\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.6cm}|
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.6cm}|
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.6cm}|}
.
.
```

I would like to reduce the width of the first column in table. To do so if I use the below:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l{1.8cm}||
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.6cm}|
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.6cm}|
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.6cm}|}
```

I get an error

```
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (1.8cm): `c' used.
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to reduce the first column width in the above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plain old left-aligned column `l` doesn't accept a width argument. If you want to specify its width, change it to `m{1.8cm}` as you did with your other columns. Of course, that will also word-wrap the text in that column if necessary.